# Is it possible to place a relative drop down box within an absolute div?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am having some difficulty and I hope someone could point me in the right direction. I am new to CSS so hopefully this is a very simple situation.

**What I want:**

I want to plant (Nest?) multiple dropdown boxes in my header that run horizontally along that header.

**What I tried:**

I tried to create a relative dropdown box and place it in an absolute header that is in a relative container.

Wrapper/Container (Relative) --> Header Div (Absolute) --> Dropdown button (Relative) --> Dropdown contents (Absolute)

**What I got:**

The relative drop down button will display under the absolute header rather than in it. The drop down box will work but it will not position itself where I want it. I'm not sure how I can get what I want.

```css
div#container {
  /*Features*/
  /*Position*/
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  left: 15%;
  /*Dimensions*/
  height: 90%;
  width: 70%;
  /*Font and colours*/
  background: gray;
}

div#header {
  /*Features*/
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  /*Dimensions*/
  height: 10%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*Font and colours*/
  background: #e67300;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}

.dropdown {
  /*Position*/
  top: 10%;
  left: 15%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  /*Position*/
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <p>Title</p>
    <div class="dropdown" style="font-size:10px">
      Mouse over me please
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you give a screenshot, or a wireframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just simply remove height property from your div#header. Hope this help

```css
div#container {
  /*Features*/
  /*Position*/
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  left: 15%;
  /*Dimensions*/
  height: 90%;
  width: 70%;
  /*Font and colours*/
  background: gray;
}

div#header {
  /*Features*/
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  /*Dimensions*/
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*Font and colours*/
  background: #e67300;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}

.dropdown {
  /*Position*/
  top: 10%;
  left: 15%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  /*Position*/
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <p>Title</p>
    <div class="dropdown" style="font-size:10px">
      Mouse over me please
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to reply but thanks for the help, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

**Add this to your css file:**

```
p{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

`<p>Title</p>` you need to know that `<p>` is a **block element** occupying a whole line.

**This is your CSS modified:**

```
div#container
{
    /*Features*/
    /*Position*/
    position:relative;
    top:5%;
    left:15%;
    /*Dimensions*/
    height:90%;
    width:70%;
    /*Font and colours*/
    background:gray;
}

div#header
{
    /*Features*/
    position:absolute;
    border-style:solid;
    /*Dimensions*/
    height:10%;
    top:0%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    /*Font and colours*/
    background:#e67300;
    text-align:center;
    clear:both;
}
p{
    display:inline-block;
}

.dropdown
    {
        /*Position*/
        top:10%;
        left:15%;
        position:relative;
        display: inline-block;

    }

    .dropdown-content
    {
        /*Position*/
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
        display:none;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
    {
        display:block;
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to reply but thanks for the help, it worked!